# Get Slider value action when editing finished Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, slider, action

I've tried "editing end" and "editing drag exit" but it doesn't work.

This works:

```
 - (IBAction)ValueChanged:(id)sender {
    int value1 = (int)(Slider1.value * 255);

    Label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", value1 ];
}


- (IBAction)TouchDown:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    int value2 = (int)(Slider1.value * 255);

    Label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", value2 ];

}
```

Nothing changes with it:

```
- (IBAction)TouchCancel:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    int value2 = (int)(Slider1.value * 255);

    Label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", value2 ];
}


- (IBAction)EditingEnd:(id)sender {
    int value2 = (int)(Slider1.value * 255);

    Label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", value2 ];
}
```

Comment: Have you set the delegate? Post some code otherwise we can't help you out. try asking a more specific question.

Comment: Why did u make my post -1 ?                                              `code` `- (IBAction)TouchCancel:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    int value2 = (int)(Slider1.value * 255);
    
    Label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", value2 ];
}

- (IBAction)EditingEnd:(id)sender {
    int value2 = (int)(Slider1.value * 255);
    
    Label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", value2 ];
} `

Comment: Please put your code in the question - not in the comment box. Also, "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything. Tell us HOW it doesn't work. Does it throw an error? Does it give you an incorrect value? The more details we have the easier it is for us to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default event that UISliders use is UIControlEventValueChanged.

After that, the method should look something like this:

```
- (IBAction)sliderAction:(id)sender {
// fun code
}
```

Comment: thanx. with value changed everything works ok and with Touch Down also , but i need action after user ended editing but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Oh, sorry! Didn't see your comment. In that case, you can use both TouchUpInside and TouchUpOutside. Not entirely perfect, but that's the only other I can think of.